# Generate a hash passwords in Node.js (Express + MongoDB)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, hash, express

How generate users passwords hash in Node.js?
I'm use Express.js and MongoDB.
I need it for authorization/registration.

Comment: https://github.com/sendanor/node-crypt3 will use password hashing built-in in your system kernel. I think it's the best approach here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [pwd](https://github.com/visionmedia/node-pwd).

Simple registration example:

```
User.count({ email: email }, function (error, count) {
        if (count === 0) {
            pwd.hash(password, function (error, salt, hash) {
                if (!error) {
                    var user = new User({
                        email: email,
                        salt: salt,
                        hash: hash
                    }).save(function (error, newUser) {
                        if (!error) {
                            User.findOne({ email: email }, function (error, user) {
                                if (!error) {
                                    if (user) {
                                        pwd.hash(password, user.salt, function (error, hash) {
                                            if (!error) {
                                                if (hash === user.hash) {
                                                    req.session.user = email;
                                                    res.json(200);
                                                } else { res.json(403, 'Password is wrong!');}
                                            }
                                        });
                                    } else { res.json(404, 'Error!'); }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        } else { res.json(409, 'User exist!'); }
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to callback hell my friend.

Comment: let Promise = require('bluebird');
let pwd = Promise.promisifyAll(require('pwd'));
pwd.hashAsync(password).then(function (salt, hash) {
// sucess code goes here
}).catch( function (error) {
 // Error code goes here. No callback hell. Nice and neat ;)
});

Answer (score 0):

Use the npm module [password-hash](https://nodejsmodules.org/pkg/password-hash)

In your server run this: `npm install password-hash`

Then in your code:

```
var hash = require("password-hash");
hash.generate(password));
```

Read over the API and you'll see it offers a variety of added security methods such as salting your password before hashing it.

Comment: Beware that the nodejsmodules.org link is dead, looks like the site was suspended at some point maybe? Looked up the package on npmjs.com and turns out it was deprecated and they suggest you use bcrypt or scrypt instead. https://www.npmjs.com/package/password-hash